# What is php-cgi56 and how can stop that for sending email?

Tags: linux, centos, security, centos7

in 2 days a go , my server(vps) running very very slow .I monitor server with `htop` monitor tool . when i view my command and service , i know some service named "php-cgi56" get all of my cpu usage and memory . This is screen shot :

http://s9.picofile.com/file/8307687218/shot.PNG

This service got all of my traffic , How can I stop that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the nginx access logs for clues, I suspect you have a contact form on a website that lacks security practices (like captcha) and is being abused for sending SPAM using php sendmail method

Comment: `php-cgi56` might be a normal process for your web server setup, depending on how exactly it has been set up. You need to study your access and error log files to see which script is run most of the time, and then study the script for possible vulnerabilities. It is also possible your server is compromised. If that is the case, then you need to restore the server from a working backup.

Answer (score 0):

kiana, Its not only the php-cgi56 which is consuming your server resources. It appears that MySQL is eating up around half of CPu i.e 45% and rest is being consumned by send mail service. Sendmail is using php to sending mails, if you have not initiated these emails via sendmail service, there may be probability of soem malicious script in your code and it could be spam. You can stop sendmail service on your system as a root by using below command.

```
  /etc/init.d/sendmail stop
```

For heavy MySQL Cpu usage, you should review the queries and may observe mysql logs closely or you may do some indexing, take a help of developer regarding indexing.